# In ARM manuals, what's the difference between res0 and res1?

Tags: arm

As appeared in register field description. For example:

> [47:0]    BADDR[47:x] 
>   Translation table base address, bits[47:x]. Bits [x-1:0] are res0.

Comment: It's a general question with regard to all ARM architecture/processor references. I should have made my title more descriptive.

Comment: that is fair but no reason to assume that all the manuals use the same terminology, and clearly you found it in one manual and that is for this question the only relevant instance.  If you want to ask about other instances in other manuals then you can list those manuals and those instances too.  if you want a now and forever read the mind of the arm tech writers, that is too broad of a question.  ten minutes from now arm can change the manual you are reading, and when that update comes out this whole question and answer becomes null and void.

Comment: @dwelch RES0 is standard terminology in ARMv8 onwards, replacing what was previously known as UNK/SBZP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RES0 is properly defined in the ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual (see also [the standard ARM glossary](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.aeg0014g/ABCDEFGH.html#CBAHEDDE)), but in summary it means a reserved field with an unknown value, which software must write with all 0s upon initialisation, then preserve (via read-modify-write operations on the register). Notably, software should not rely on the field subsequently reading back as 0.

RES1, as you might imagine by now, is exactly the same only with 1s instead of 0s (i.e. initialising with all bits set).

This is essentially a forwards-compatibility promise that if any part of that field gets repurposed to mean something in a future version of the architecture, the current reserved value will be the 'safe' setting which preserves the current behaviour. Occasionally it is also used to preserve backwards-compatibility where an obsolete feature has been removed (e.g. most the the reserved SCTLR bits).

Comment: I know a lot of people will get what `s/0/1/` is, but you might want to consider saying something like "with 1 instead of 0", as those who don't get the regex reference will probably be confused.

Comment: @rjp True, it was a little too terse. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Is is also worth noting that the Glossary Notlikethat linked to is also part of the ARM Architecture Reference Manual ARMv8 PDF currently located at: https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/a/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile
version DDI0487A_j_armv8_arm which is the end-all-be-all ARMv8 reference.

The GLOSSARY appears at the end of that document in a "magic" section without section number.